# phalcon query return Scanning error before

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm using the phalcon framework, I want to execute this query

```
public function updateAction($id)
{
$email = $this->request->getPost('email');
 $check_email_unique = Users::find(['conditions' => 'id != ' .$id. ' AND email = '. $email]);

echo $check_email_unique->id;
return ;
    }
```

but when test, the function on postman this returns error 
[image]

Comment: You must as single quote ["conditions"=> '"id != '" .$id. "' AND email = '". $email."'"]

Comment: sorry but not work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be binding your parameters because what you are doing is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Try this:

```php
$check_email_unique = Users::findFirst([
    'conditions' => "email = :email: AND id != :id:",
    'bind' => [
        'email' => $email,
        'id' => $id
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all .. i solved my problem like that :

```
    public function updateAction($id)
        {
        $email = $this->request->getPost('email');
        $check_email_unique = Users::findFirst(['conditions' => "email = '".$email."' AND id != '".$id."'"]);

    echo  $check_email_unique->id; 
return ;
    }
```

Comment: This answer is vulnerable to injection attacks. You need to be binding your parameters as stated above.

Comment: There is a better way on this by binding-it